# Magento 2 - Disable caching of prices on category view

Tags: magento2, price, cache

I have a Magento 2.2.4 store where prices are automatically updated every 10 minutes from an stock management system. This works fine on product pages and any custom 'featured products' sections etc, but on category pages the prices are stuck and not updating.

Any way I can change this so the prices are not cached on category pages?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late comment but the best solution for this case would be removing price box from the page and use a sub-request to load latest price information and append to the page so you don't have any problem with caching and keep the page with newest price.

Hope the idea helps someone else.

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Answer (score -1):

You can disable caching in this class "FinalPriceBox"

I used to do override this class

> \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox

add to your di.xml file this line

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox"  type="{vendor}\{module}\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox"/>
```

then create **FinalPriceBox.php** file in this path **{vendor}{module}\Pricing\Render**

```
<?php

namespace {vendor}\{module}\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;
use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Pricing\Renderer\SalableResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{

    public function getCacheLifetime()
    {
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that by adding this the entire category page will become non-cacheable. As the Magento 2 developer documentation notes: `Do not configure content pages (i.e., catalog, product, and CMS pages) to be uncacheable. Doing so has an adverse affect on performance.`